# Angular Code Inside Subscribe() How to Run Synchronouly

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, observable, subscribe

```js
_subscriptions.push(
  // Update list on OG selection
  ogViewModel.current$.subscribe(
    (group) => {
      this.groupUuid = group.ogUuid;
      this.groupId = group.id;
      this.getDevices();
      this.getSubOgs();
      this.updateGroup(group);
    },
  ),
```

I have a block of code inside subscribe. However, it seems that they are not executed in order. this.getSubOgs() is executed before this.getDevices(). Both are HTTP calls that returns an observable. How do I make sure this.getDevices() is executed first?
[Click to See Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP7dv.png)

Comment: You can try putting this.getSubOgs() at the end of this.getDevices() method

Comment: use async await to run them synchronously

Comment: @PiyushJain How to use async await here? I am new to angular and subcription.

Comment: @MishaMashina I can't put this.getSubOgs() at the end of this.getDevices() method because they are two separate methods that need to be referenced in other places.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan Unfortunately I can't provide more codes since they are industry codes. However, in both getDevices() and getSubOgs(), we call the method that makes an HTTP call and return the result as an observable.

Comment: @CindyZhang - you could've at least posted the content of that screen shot as code; makes it more readable.

Comment: As an aside: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan You can click on the link in the post, it will show you the screenshot of the codes.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I'm confused. Why is the observable even pushed into an array? What's the goal of this? But if you want to use several observables in succession, you might want to look into mergeMap() in RxJs

Comment: use [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) rxjs/operator

Answer (score 0):

this is basically @MishaMashina's suggestion

```
    _subscriptions.push(ogViewModel.current$.subscribe(
    (group) => {
      this.groupUuid = group.ogUuid;
      this.groupId = group.id;
      this.getDevices();
      this.updateGroup(group);
    },
  ),
```

both getDevices() and getSubOgs() remain seperate methods

in

```
public getDevices() { this.myApiClient.getDevices().Subscribe(
let onlyThisTime: boolean = true;
    (next) => doStuff
    (error) => doErrorStuff
    () => {if(onlyThisTime){this.getSubOgs();}}
    )}
```